# Pandas use multiple conditions for assigning values in a column:

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: `Role`, `to_group1`, `to_group2`, `remove` and i would like to assign `True` where the value in `to_group1` AND `to_group2` are nan, but it seems that my code is not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
df.remove = np.where(((df.to_group1 == np.nan)) & ((df.to_group2 == 
np.nan)), True, np.nan)
```

with this code I only get the column `remove` full of nan.

This is an example of my table:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| role | to_group1 | to_group2 | remove |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| foo  | nan       | 1         | nan    |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| foo1 | nan       | nan       | 1      |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| bar  | 1         | nan       | nan    |
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Moreover, I already initialised my column `remove` with some values, and I dont want to reassign the the whole column new values, I just want to "put a true where both conditions are satisfied" and don't modify anything else.

Comment: You want `df.remove = np.where((pd.isnull(aws.to_group1)) & (pd.isnull(aws.to_group2)), True, np.nan)` you can't compare with `NaN` directly using `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) instead of `== np.nan`

```
df['remove'] = np.where(df.to_group1.isnull() & df.to_group2 .isnull(), True, np.nan)

0    NaN
1    1
2    NaN
```

---

For the edited, suppose you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.nan, 2, 3], 'col2': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4]})
df['remove'] = 'some_initia_val'


    col1    col2    remove
0   1.0     NaN     'some_initia_val'
1   NaN     NaN     'some_initia_val'
2   2.0     3.0     'some_initia_val'
3   3.0     4.0     'some_initia_val'
```

The use boolean masking

```
df.loc[df.col1.isnull() & df.col2.isnull(), 'remove'] = True
```

To change only the one value where conditions meet

```
    col1    col2    remove
0   1.0     NaN     'some_initia_val'
1   NaN     NaN     True
2   2.0     3.0     'some_initia_val'
3   3.0     4.0     'some_initia_val'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally make it work, big thanks to EdChum that came first!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem ;} Notice that you can use `pd.isnull(series)` or simply `series.isnull()` as I suggested. Personally I believe the latter is less verbose, but they do pretty much the same thing

Comment: But what if before I already initialised some values in remove, so that I dont want to change the remove column, but only update it?

Comment: You can use boolean mask. Update the question with this detail and I can update the answer ;}

Answer (score 0):

This is a known idiosyncrasy: `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`. You can get round this, as stated, via [`pd.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html).

Alternatively, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df['remove'] = np.where(df[['to_group1', 'to_group2']].isnull().all(1), True, np.nan)
```